# Thinkpad Edge 15 - Wake from hibernation issues after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, hibernate, thinkpad

After upgrading Ubuntu from 10.10 to 11.10 (though 11.04) the hibernation fails once in a while.

With 10.10 I used uswsusp - it does not work at all on 11.10 (uninstalled) so I use ordinary swsusp. The ordinary hibernation fails to start once in a while:

- Sometimes starts clearly after hibernation without problems
- Sometimes I get kernel panic
- Sometimes it just reboots itself.
- Happens with Unity, Gnome, XFCE and KDE.
- The behavior is not consistent

Any ideas how can it be fixed or at least properly debugged?

Comment: Did you try to update the BIOS downloading the update from lenovo's website?

Comment: No, I didn't. Does this update known to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could start debugging by looking at `/var/log/pm-*.log` and the scripts in the `pm-utils` package (`dpkg -l pm-utils`). "pm" stands for Power Management, and is invoked for each hibernate/wake/suspend/resume. Do you have encrypted swap? suspend/resume has trouble with that.

Comment: I had awarded the bounty to prevent from it being wasted, and because it was the only answer and it was reasonable (even thou obvious)

Answer (score 0):

watch out with swsusp!!

...

```
"* If you touch anything on disk between suspend and resume... 
*...kiss your data goodbye.
* If you do resume from initrd after your filesystems are mounted...
*...bye bye root partition.
```

...

from: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt